# VideoView callback end video

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using this piece of code in order to play a video:

```
string videoUriString = "android.resource://" +  this.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.video;
Android.Net.Uri videoURI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(videoUriString);
video.SetVideoURI(videoURI);
video.Start();
```

But I am really frustrated because I don't understand how attach a callback for handle the end of the video, I have to use Monodroid, then C#

Answer (score 10):

```
 myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           //write your code after complete video play  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach the callback by

```
video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Android :

```
video.Completion += delegate {
    Finish();
};
```