# How to schedule 3 tasks one by one in android?

Tags: android

I have a relative layout and I have added it to horizontal scrollview. Now what I want is whenever user presses on the layout the first thing it should do is, play the tts, secondly it should play a video and thirdly it should start a timer. All the things should be done one by one. Can anyone tell me how to schedule these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper callback to detect the completion of speech. Check this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409177/unable-to-detect-completion-of-tts-callback-android)

and this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520977/videoview-callback-end-video)

for the video completion callback.